# Error: “ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded”

Tags: python, json, export-to-csv

Following is my Simple JSON code which is showing the

> error: "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"

```
import csv, json

infile = open("01_ZD_20180501_00407_001.json","r")
outfile = open("01_ZD_20180501_00407_001.csv","w")

writer = csv.writer(outfile)

for row in json.loads(infile.read()):
    writer.writerow(row)
```

errors show like below
[image]

Comment: Why do you think the input is JSON?

Comment: confirm whether the infile is a json or not.

Comment: Also you should use json.load(fp) for reading a json from a file.

Comment: @TheCreator232 no hi didn't, `json.load()` work when read from file, but `json.loads()` read from string, in this case `json.loads(infile.read())` he read the file, in this case `infile.read()` return `str`

Comment: sorry about the mistake, it is json file

Comment: @zimdero: Yes, that's correct. But I was passing the file pointer (fp) as the argument in json.load. Both ways are correct, I was just pointing out an alternative option.

Comment: Your code says otherwise.

Comment: sorry, I am still confused about this case, I am a freshman, thank you for all of your help!

Comment: if you try to read a pretty printed JSON file, line by line, the json.loads function probably won't be able to parse it.

Comment: If you take your JSON text, and make it "compact" with this tool, https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ does it read then? I think the "for row in json..." line will only work if you have a json structured as a list at the top level, and not a dictionary. You might break that into two lines and test it is a list `print type(myjson)` first.

Comment: also, this may seem silly to mention, but there a lot of online csv to json converters for one-off conversions.